# Cannot see file(s) in sharing folder

Tags: samba, file-sharing, cifs

A very ‘green’ newbie here, so please bear with me.  I looked through existing threads but not quite seeing an answer.

I got sharing set up on my Ubuntu and Windows 7 Pro machines, and I have sharing folders on both desktops.  I have CIFS ***and*** Samba set up in Ubuntu, including computer name, user name and password.  However, at this point, when I place a ‘test’ file in the Windows sharing folder, I am still not seeing it displayed in the Ubuntu sharing folder.  I’m not finding any answers or solutions, and I’m running out of things (ways) to google.

Again, I am very new to Linux/Ubuntu (14.04) ... I don’t know if I’m doing something wrong, or if there’s something else left undone.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you cannot see the files, it this on the file manager (Nautilus?).  Have you tried pressing F5 to refresh?  Can you see the files from the command line? CTRL+ALT+T then `cd folder_name` to the folder you have placed files in and do `ls -al`

Answer (score 0):

You may check the rights of the shared folder on Windows 7 side (Right Click > Property > Security tab) and check if your user as the appropriate rights.

Comment: Thank you, olivierb2, but I looked and I already have full permissions in the Security tab for the Sharing folder (in Win7).

Comment: Are you able to create a file from Ubuntu in the shared folder? Did you see it then from Windows?

Comment: Silly of me to not try things in reverse.  Unfortunately, it's the same situation -- after putting a file in the Ubuntu sharing folder, it does not appear in the Win7 sharing folder.

Comment: It sounds like the shared folder is definitely not the one you think.

Comment: Thanks again, olivierb2, but I checked on this, and I have full rights for the Sharing folder.

Comment: "The shared folder is definitely not the one you think."?  Why would that be?  To do things safely, what precisely should I do to dump everything I've done, and start over on creating sharing between the two PCs?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on an old CentOS7 Samba installation.
The quick solution was to set **selinux to permissive**. After a restart of the smb service all files were visible.

```
# setenforce 0
```

Or change the selinux config file.

Comment: That is a CentOS command and does not exist on Ubuntu. When I search that command does not seem to even have anything to do with Samba.